# Building a list of "incremental sums"

Tags: scala, collections

What is an efficient, functional way of building a list of "incremental sums"

For example, given

```
val (a,b,c,d) = (2,3,5,6)
val list1 = List(a, b, c, d)
```

How would you implement f such as:

```
list1.map(f)
```

would result in

```
List(a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you do

```
list1.scanLeft(0)(_ + _).tail
```

?